# Normalisation / 3nf in database

Tags: database, database-normalization, 3nf

I have this table (Day, Employee no, Employee Name, Client no, Client name, Product no, Product Description, Unit Price, Quantity Sold, Total Sales)

Example data :

```
22nd, e123,  Dave,   c1264,  Sheila, p15462,  Hoover, 4.50,  5, --
----, ----,  -----,  c64402, Jovek,  p673431, Kettle, 2.25, 10, 45
----, e4215, Johnny, c785,   Keith,  p15462,  Hoober, 4.50,  2,  9
23rd, e123,   Dave,  c64402, Jovek,  p673431, Kettle, 2.25, 20, --
```

So basically, there is only data for the day if its a new day entry, and there is only a total for total sales, after all the sales that an employee has made.

So far, I have got :

```
Product(ProdNo#,ProductDesc,Price)
Client(ClientNo#, ClientName)
Employee(EmployeeNo#, EmployeeName)
```

However, I'm unsure what to do regarding the individual sales and total sales for every day?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You just need one more table to capture all the data. It should be for a sale and link back to the tables you describe above. it has to have a date, of course.

Comment: You have given an example of an initial "table". But the row order matters, so it is not a relational table. So normalization makes no sense. However, judging from what you probably want the alternate tables to contain, you don't seem to care about the order. So it seems like we can just replace all "---" Day, Employee No & Employee Name subrows with the most recent values above, and all "---" "Total Sales" subrows with the next value down to get a table holding rows where "on day Day an employee with number Employee No and name Employee Name ...". ...

Comment: .... Then to normalize to 3NF or BCNF we need to know all *functional dependencies* (FDs). What are yours? If you don't know what a FD is, you don't know what normalization is. So please give all FDs, and if you need to find out what an FD or normalization is, please find out. If you get stuck, then please explain where you got to and what you're stuck on.

Comment: PS What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical example for the use of a [star- or snowflake schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

The tables Product, Customer, Employee are called **dimension tables**.

The **fact table** has foreign keys to the dimension table and contains a quantity, e.g. the concrete sale.

```
Sales(ProdNo#, ClientNo#, EmployeeNo#, Sale)
```

The primary key of is a [compound key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) of `ProdNo#, ClientNo#, EmployeeNo#`.

Total sales would not be modelled explicitly but queried via aggregation, e.g.

```
SELECT  P.ProdNo, SUM(S.sale)
FROM Products P, Sales S
WHERE P.Price > 1000 AND S.ProdNo = P.ProdNo
GROUP BY P.ProdNo
```

The RDBMS or data warehouse will optimize the query, so total sales do need to be modeled explicitly (no denormalization).

Comment: This answer fails to claim or justify that its proposals is in 3NF, which is what the question is (unclearly) asking for. Also, normalization does not add or drop columns, it replaces a table by others using the same columns that always join to it.